# How can I use Rails' has_many with where condition using in factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In `user.rb` I am using:

```
has_many :family, -> { where ["user_type = 'family'"] }
has_one :friend, -> { where ["user_type = 'friend'"] }
```

I want to use a `has_many` conditions row in my user factory under `traits`. How can I do this?

My factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do

  trait :with_family_photo do
    after(:create) do |photo|
      photo.portrait_type 'portrait_type'
      photo.family_photos << FactoryGirl.create(:with_family_photo, photo_id: photo.id)
    end
  end

  trait :with_friends_photo do
    after(:create) do |photo|
      photo.portrait_type 'portrait_photo'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @SRack for your edition +1